# Unable to open dialer when user clicks on the button in xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode

```
-(IBAction)didSelectButton:(id)sender
{
   NSString *numberString = @"415-592-5909";
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",numberString]]];
}
```

I have this code to open the dialer, but it doesn't work in Xcode 7. So when i searched i got that i have to whitelist the tel url scheme, so i did something like this in info.plist

```
<key> LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>telprompt</string>
    <string>tel</string>
</array>
```

Comment: And then what happens ?are you still facing any issue?

Comment: yes i am still facing the issue, i have ipad device with ios 8 in which i am trying to run this code but nothing happens, and i get an message in debugger for the tel url scheme.

Comment: @uzairdhada Check the answer. Hope it help you.

Comment: i get message in debugger as 'LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme tel'

Comment: @Ashish Kakkas, After using telprompt, i am getting a prompt with number as title and two buttons, one as cancel and another as call, when i click on call nothing happens. what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added one Space before the key

```
<key> LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
```

update it with

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
```

Hope you are getting following error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException',
>   reason: 'tel is missing from your Info.plist under
>   LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0'

Just update the key with :

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>telprompt</string>
    <string>tel</string>
</array>
```

And to open the prompt you have to use `telprompt`

Comment: still nothing happens

Comment: @uzairdhada and your device has Sim card?

Comment: I am sorry it was so silly mistake, its working fine after inserting sim, thank you much. @Ashish Kakkad